# "VSDebug Message" dialog appears when using a keyboard shortcut

Tags: visual-studio

When I make Build Solution command in VS2015 Update 2 using ctrl+shift+B shortcut I have a error:

```
---------------------------
VSDebug Message
---------------------------
Command data:



    Guid = {5EFC7975-14BC-11CF-9B2B-00AA00573819}

    GuidID = 11

    CmdID = 882

    Type = 0x00000001

    Flags = 0x00000048

    Canonical name = Build.BuildSolution

    Localized name = (Not set)
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

It works well if I use mouse. Cleaning Cache and even reinstall doesn't help. How to resolve it?

Comment: Is shortcut `ctrl+shift+B` in build menu item?

Comment: Sure it is there. Additionally I tried to reassign. Same result.

Comment: Is there more information in activity log?

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may have VSIP logging enabled, in which it case you can disable it if you have a ***Disable VSIP Logging*** item in the **View** menu.

You can also make sure that the registry value, `EnableVSIPLogging`, in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\General\`, is set to `0`.

See also https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dr._ex/2007/04/17/using-enablevsiplogging-to-identify-menus-and-commands-with-vs-2005-sp1/.

[image: View menu]